# How to enforce window aspect ratio for a SwiftUI app on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Adding an `aspectRatio` modifier seems no effect on the window.

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .frame(minWidth: windowSize().minWidth, minHeight: windowSize().minHeight)
        .frame(maxWidth: windowSize().maxWidth, maxHeight: windowSize().maxHeight)
        .aspectRatio(2/1, contentMode: .fill)
}
```

The definition for the `windowSize` struct used in the code snippet above

```
struct windowSize {
    let minWidth : CGFloat = 200
    let minHeight : CGFloat = 100
    let maxWidth : CGFloat = 600
    let maxHeight : CGFloat = 300
}
```